# Postman: How to assert situation when service is down

Tags: postman, runner

Currently Postman seems to unable to assert situation when testing service doesn't work. I suppose to make in-test call before main request:

```
pm.sendRequest(str function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        postman.setNextRequest(null);
    } else {
        pm.environment.set("variable_key", "new_value");
    }
});
```

The question is how to stop collection run without even calling the first collection request if service does not response?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the decision:

```
pm.sendRequest(str, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
    tests["Service does not response " +str] = false;
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
} else {
    pm.environment.set("variable_key", "new_value");
}
});
```

PS: I was looking for an option to mark iteration failed in Newman, but it appeared to be a newman [bug](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1600). Iterations with failed asserts are to be failed.
Looks like you cant skip current step, but you will see an error for failed requests:

```
failed requests: 1
1.  Error          connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.6:8009
                at request
               inside "Step 2"
```